# Setting Parse.serverURL not working

Tags: react-native, parse-platform

I created a react native project.

My dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
"events": "^1.1.1",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"parse": "^1.10.0",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.48.4",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router-native": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"timers": "^0.1.1"
}
```

So basically when I tried to configure the Parse connections I did it on App.js on componentWillMount(), like so:

```
componentWillMount(){ Parse.initialize("AppId","JSKey"); Parse.serverURL = 'http://parseServer:1337/parse' }
```

Everything works fine until Parse.intialize, but when trying to set the serverURL I get this error:

```
https://api.parse.com/1 is not a function (evaluating '_reactNative3.default.serverURL('http://parseServer:1337/parse')') componentWillMount
```